# C# Anonymous collection initializer for a method dictionary

Tags: c#

Trying to make a dictionary that stores methods, those methods create stuff in windows forms, etc.

The method takes no parameters and returns Dictionary of all the items created.

```
Dictionary<string, Func<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>> games = new 
Dictionary<string, Func<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>>()
{
    { "Buttoncatch", //I dont know what to write here
        {
           var objects = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>
           return objects;
        }
    }
};
```

I do not want to do this:

```
public Dictionary<string, dynamic> Buttoncatch()
{

}
games["Buttoncatch"] = Buttoncatch //dont even know what to write here, 
problems of self teaching
```

Comment: Don't use `dynamic` unless you *really* know what you're doing.  Look into [delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the value type of your dictionary `dynamic`, it can be `Func<Dictionary<string,dynamic>>`.

And the methods can be created as normal lambdas:

```
Dictionary<string, Func<Dictionary<string,dynamic>>> games = new     
Dictionary<string, Func<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>>
{
   {"Buttoncatch", 
    () => {
             var objects = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>
             return objects;
          }
   }
};
```

And when you declare the dictionary that way, the line

```
games["Buttoncatch"] = Buttoncatch;
```

will work, too.